# Javascript line-break not working

Tags: javascript, html, line-breaks

I have this really big text where I want to add line breaks in order to look better on my application. I have tried using

`"<br>", "\n"`

to cut the text in pieces. I have ven tried to change the width of the span but nothing seems to be working. What am I doing wrong? Any help appreciated.

```
<span id="instr" style="color: white; font-size: 15pt;"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
function instructions(){
....

document.getElementById("instr").textContent = "Really biiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiig text here";

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set `<br />` line breaks you need to use `innerHTML` property:

```
document.getElementById("instr").innerHTML = "Really<br />biiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiig<br/ >text here";
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the CSS `white-space` property to wrap text.  See here for more information:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/white-space

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementById("instr").innerHTML` to insert `<br>`.

Answer (score 0):

since span is inline element, I would not use it. I would try div or p elements. If you have to, look into word-wrap property

Answer (score -1):

Just use `innerText` instead of `textContent`. Then you can use `\n`.

```
document.getElementById("instr").innerText = "Really biiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiig\n text here";
```

Or use `innerHTML` along with `<br/>`.

```
document.getElementById("instr").innerHTML = "Really biiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiig<br/> text here";
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phCmH/

Comment: In won't set line breaks to HTML markup, `<br />` tags required.

Comment: OP only needs the text in multiple lines.